# Angularjs twitter bootstrap. Error: element.focus() is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, focus

I made use of angularjs twitter bootstrap datepicker. Everything is working fine. But it throws an error when i click on the text box for popup datepicker. What will be the problem. I am new to angularjs.

Here is the javascript i have used

```
            scope.today = function() {
                scope.dt = new Date();
            };
            scope.today();

            scope.showWeeks = false;
            scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
                scope.showWeeks = ! scope.showWeeks;
            };

            scope.clear = function () {
                scope.dt = null;
            };

            scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
                return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
            };

            scope.toggleMin = function() {
                scope.minDate = ( scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
            };
            scope.toggleMin();
```

And the html is

```
<div class="controls">
     <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy" ng-model="dt" min="'1950-06-22'" max="'2050-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" />
</div>
```

Am i missing anything. Hoping for a solution..

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
    <input type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" 
    bs-datepicker="bs-datepicker" b-datepicker="{{dateOptions}}" ng-model="dt" >
      </input>
```

Comment: <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy" ng-model="dt"  min="'1950-06-22'" max="'2050-06-22'" b-datepicker="{{dateOptions}}"  datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" />
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

Whoever facing this problem, The straight forward solution is to load the bootstrap or the datepicker module at the end.
This error is thrown when the modules and libraries which the datepicker is dependent on, Loads after datepicker. Just ensure Datepicker is loaded at the end.